# how to detect shared letter between two words in regex in c++

Tags: c++, regex, algorithm

my problem is detection shared letter between two word and is like:
I have"

> twone or eightwo or nineight ...

strings and I want to extract all numbers in this string now I have

> "two" and "one" ,or "eight" and "two" or "nine" and "eight"

,
so I need to have both of them
but in my regex pattern it does not happen ,
when it detects "two" , it can not detect"one" any more.
this is my code:

```
 std::map<std::string, std::string> wordToDigit = {
        {"zero", "0"},
        {"one", "1"},
        {"two", "2"},
        {"three", "3"},
        {"four", "4"},
        {"five", "5"},
        {"six", "6"},
        {"seven", "7"},
        {"eight", "8"},
        {"nine", "9"}
        
    };
    std::string inputString ="eightwo"; //this is another example.
    std::regex pattern("(?:zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine\\d+)");
    std::sregex_iterator it(inputString.begin(), inputString.end(), pattern);
    std::sregex_iterator end;
    std::vector<std::string> allDigits;
    while (it != end) {
        allDigits.push_back(it->str());
        ++it;
    }
   
    if (!allDigits.empty()) {
        std::vector<std::string> allNumericDigits;
        for (const std::string& digit : allDigits) {
            if(wordToDigit[digit] ==""){
            allNumericDigits.push_back(digit);
            }else{
              allNumericDigits.push_back(wordToDigit[digit]);
            }
            
        }

        
        std::string firstDigit = allNumericDigits.front();
        std::string lastDigit = allNumericDigits.back();

        std::string concatenatedNumberStr = firstDigit + lastDigit;
        int concatenatedNumber = std::stoi(concatenatedNumberStr);

        
       
       std::cout << concatenatedNumber;
        return concatenatedNumber;
    }
```

Comment: `regex` is probably not the right tool for the job... Also, this code is clearly not C, so don't tag C

Comment: regular expressions is rarely the answer.

Comment: look for word, remove word, repeat.  do this for all words you are looking for.

Comment: Are words like `mininetwork` or `nonerroneous` or `honeymooner` supposed to find the substrings as match words?

Comment: You have a problem.  You think "I know, I can use regular expressions!".  You now have two problems: the original problem, and regular expressions.  Regular expressions are great for an interactive editing session to fix up some data on one-off use.  Any other use, please don't.  Any problem too complex to solve in a dozen characters is easier solved another way, and it scales HORRIBLY.  (For those sub-dozen character cases, it rocks)

Comment: Advent of Code inspired question?

Comment: yes actually I got stock in part two of advent of code Day 1;

Comment: "mininetwork" here just we have "nine".

Comment: Hint: `string::find()` and `string::rfind()`. Trying to use regular expressions tends to make this problem more difficult than it actually is.

Comment: Could you not attempt to match the regular expression `\b(?:twone|oneight|threeight|fiveight|nineight|sevenine|eightwo)\b` and if there is a match obtain the desired pair of strings from the dictionary `{{"twone", ["two", "one"]}, {"oneight", ["one", "eight"]}, {"threeight", ["three", "eight"]}, {"fiveight", ["five", "eight"]}, {"nineight", ["nine", "eight"]}, 
{"sevenine", ["seven", "nine"]}, {"eightwo"=>["eight", "two"]}}`? My apologies if I have not written that correctly for C#.

Answer (score 3):

regexes can be quite powerfull but have their limitations and the overhead is usually not worth it. Online demo : https://onlinegdb.com/dxjyDk0E7

(@Eljay this code will find two `one` instances in `nonerroneous`)

```
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// A matcher helper that keeps track for each word
// you want to detect how many letters it has seen
// (I do make use of the fact that words for numbers do not have repeated sequences)
struct matcher_t
{
    bool match(const char c)
    {
        // each time a letter matches we increase matched
        if (word[matched] == c)
        {
            matched++;
            // if the number of letters matches the size of the word
            // its a match
            if (matched == word.size())
            {
                matched = 0;
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            matched = 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    std::string_view word;
    std::size_t matched;
};

auto detect_numbers(std::string_view input)
{
    static std::vector<matcher_t> matchers
    {
        { "zero", 0 },
        { "one", 0 },
        { "two", 0},
        { "three", 0 },
        { "four", 0 },
        { "five", 0 },
        { "six", 0 },
        { "seven", 0 },
        { "eight", 0 },
        { "nine", 0 }
    };

    std::vector<std::string_view> matches;

    // loop once over the input string
    for (const auto c : input)
    {
        // and use the matcher for each individual word.
        for (auto& matcher : matchers)
        {
            if (matcher.match(c))
            {
                // if it is a match add another string_view
                // to the vector of matches
                matches.push_back(matcher.word);
                matcher.matched = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

int main()
{
    std::string input{ "twone or eightwo or nineight" };
    auto numbers = detect_numbers(input);

    for (const auto& number : numbers)
    {
        std::cout << number << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: as well I have to detect numbers as well like "1gftwone78" the output should be 12178 for numerical part I need use regex like 1 to 9?

Comment: @NegarNasiri -- you don't "need" a regular expression to detect digits; that's one way to do it, but there are others. Identifying digits is simple: a character `ch` is a digit if `std::isdigit(ch)` is not zero.

Comment: I am new to c ++, let me check it, thanks for helping

Comment: This is not really about C++ it is about thinking about how to solve problems. My example might not even be the most efficient it is mainly to show there are many possible solutions. Don't worry too much, trying to use the standard library first was a good first step by you and something you should keep trying. Use STL first... but if you can't get it to work at all, sometimes writing some code/algorithm from scratch is what you have to do. :)

Comment: now I completely get confused to figure out what you did in the code :) I am trying to understand  your solution and your logic to solving it

Comment: can I replece  {
        { "zero", 0 },
        { "one", 0 },
        { "two", 0},
        { "three", 0 },
        { "four", 0 },
        { "five", 0 },
        { "six", 0 },
        { "seven", 0 },
        { "eight", 0 },
        { "nine", 0 }
    }; by  {
        { "zero", 0 },
        { "one", 1 },
        { "two", 2},
        { "three", 3 },
        { "four", 4 },
        { "five", 5 },
        { "six", 6 },
        { "seven", 7 },
        { "eight", 8 },
        { "nine", 9 }
    };

Comment: for (char c : input)
    {
        if (std::isdigit(c))
        {
            // Convert the digit character to a string before pushing into matches
           matches.emplace_back(std::string(1, c));
        }
        else
        {
         for (auto& matcher : matchers)
            {
                if (matcher.match(c))
                {
                 matches.push_back(matcher.word);
                    matcher.matched = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: I tried above code to detect numerical character as well, but it gives me wrong answer

Comment: like 2twonehg75 ----> 22175

Comment: OFcourse if gives the wrong answer my example code is looking for characters next to each other. How to find 22175 requires you to find numbers anywhere... now you just have to go over the input string use std::isdgit to pick out the characters you need and put them together in a new string.